# Hallow spell with regard to spells cast outside of it

Tags: dnd-5e, curse-of-strahd

We’re playing *Curse of Strahd* and we’re at the very end.

My party has Ireena locked up with tons of guards in St. Andrals Church, and what I’m planning to do is have Strahd fire bomb it from above with spells, and as it burns and collapses he’ll run out and snatch her. Now, the church has *hallow* on it so he can’t enter. I just wanted to make sure he can firebomb it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG SE. You normally should indicate the rpg and edition in the tags that your question is for, as the answers can differ. I think this is for D&D 5e, as Curse of Strahd is a D&D 5e module, and will do it for you, if this is not correct please change it. Also, it might be useful take some time to check out the tour in the help section.

Answer (score 5):

### Strahd would be unlikely to do this

[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) says:

> First, celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and undead can't enter the area, nor can such creatures charm, frighten, or possess creatures within it.

Nothing prevents creatures from outside the area to cast spells into the area, they only cannot enter it. So, Strahd could *fireball* the church without problem.

However, he is unlikely to do so. Strahd sees his long lost love in Ireena. Setting the church on fire until it collapes has a high risk of just killing her in the conflagration. Furthermore, until the church collapses, it still would be under the protection of *hallow*, so he could not sneak in and snatch her out of the flames before then.

---

P.S. Normally the *hallow* spell emanates from a point in space, and would not stop working just because the church collapses. Here the adventure says the church is hallowed ground "*as though **the building** was protected by a* hallow *spell*". So it would be a question wether you as a DM consider the collaped building to still be a building, or not. If yes, the protection would continue.

Comment: Why would _hallow_ stop protecting, even after the church burns to the ground? The spell has a duration of "Until dispelled" and a ranch of "Touch". From the spell description, _"You touch a point and **infuse an area around it** with holy (or unholy) power."_ Even without a church, the "point" would still exist.

Comment: @MivaScott Funny that you ask, I had a whole paragraph on it in draft. The adventure says the building is protected as under the effect of an hallow spell. It would be debatable if a collapsed builiding still counts as a building, and I think likely not, (cf. is a smashed chair still a chair?), or at least, that is a DM call, and here the DM wants it to end. I can add it back in.

Comment: It's really more of a question of if *it is* the hallow spell, or *as though* there was a hallow spell. If it's really the spell, then it's based on a point that just encompasses the building (I don't know it's size, is it bigger than 60ft radius?) in which case the building doesn't matter. If it's "as though", then it's up to the DM to decide if the building is responsible for the effects or it's the spell that is shaped to be within he confines of the church.

Comment: @MivaScott Yes. The text says “as though”.